# How do I stop auto arranging feature with in a cdkDropList

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop

I would like to drag & drop an item within a cdkDropList but don't want the auto arrange of those items in list. Want to drop an item in middle or right and keep that place. Now it's coming closest available left align space automatically when I release my mouse.

```
<div cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="items" cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="item" *ngFor="let item of items;">
        {{item.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am following https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview as an example

Comment: What have you tried thus far? We can't be expected to do your work for you.

Comment: @MikeTung I want to render some items with predefined position within multiple rows. Items are draggable and user can add or modify any item's position among those rows before saving. All items have unique id.

`<div *ngFor="let row of rows;" cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="items" cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="item" *ngFor="let item of items;">
        {{item.name}}
    </div>
</div>`